# Jquery AJAX ($.get or $.ajax) HTML File retrieval, Manipulation, and JSON Send

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm facing an issue where I need to open an html file via Ajax, Modify it, and send it else where via ajax(JSON)

The Below is the HTML file that I'm opening

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
>     <head>
>         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
>         <title>Message</title>   
>     </head>
>     <body>  <div id="test"></div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Below is the first javascript function I created. This was not working for me because it stripped out the Doctype and html tags of the html document being opened:

```
function sendEmailFromTemplate(templateLocation) {
    $.get(templateLocation, function (data) { 

  data = $(data)
data.find("#test").html("testing")
        data = $('<div/>').append(data.clone()).html()

        $.ajax({ //sends data
            type: "POST",
            url: "secretlocation.aspx",
            data: JSON.stringify({ fromEmail: "test@test.com", fromAbrv: "test", userEmail: $("#txtEmail").val(), message: data }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {


            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    })




}
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Message</title>   
    </head>
    <body>  <div id="test">{message}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
function sendEmailFromTemplate(templateLocation) {
    $.get(templateLocation, function (data) { 

        data = data.replace(/({message})/g,"Here be my messagem");//putting message

        $.ajax({ //sends data
            type: "POST",
            url: "secretlocation.aspx",
            data: { fromEmail: "test@test.com", fromAbrv: "test", userEmail: $("#txtEmail").val(), message: data },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {


            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: This is not the issue. the ajax function works fine, the issue I'm facing is that when I convert data to a jquery object it strips out the HTML tags and Doctype

Comment: It is not possible to serialize the entire document ,
 the jquery will create a  DOM object collections, I will edit my answer with a solution which can be useful

Comment: Very Good Solution! Didn't think of doing that... I'm going to wait a couple of days to see if more answers come in to get some more input before I choose the answer. Thanks!

Comment: welcome, I changed my answer again, i added a regular expression for replace function. I believe is better than the previous